# Web app. Keep link extension in web view, open root domain in Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-applications, uiwebview

I am working on a web-app in Xcode. I want my code to keep any link clicked in the app containing a specific part of a URL to stay inside the web view. Anything that’s not containing the URL specified to open in Safari. I am using the code shown bellow. The issue is that the web app is not hosted on the root domain, and I want the root domain to open in safari.

Example:
Web app located at : webapp.com/location/1

Main page: webapp.com

I want everything that is located at: webapp.com/location/1 to stay in the web view.

Anything that’s from the main page at webapp.com to open in safari.

I tried to add the /location/1 to the string, but that ended up with making it invalid and opening every URL in safari.

Code used:

```
- (BOOL)shouldOpenInSafari:(NSURL*)url
{
    if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"mailto"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([url.host isEqualToString:@"webapp.com"]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I tried to change it to this, with no luck:

```
    else if ([url.host isEqualToString:@"webapp.com/location/1"]) {
        return NO;
    }
```